# Ping a hostname with Service name

Tags: ping

I am unable to reach my database getting error message as "login timeout connecting to the database". I need to ping the Database server .Could you please tell how to ping server with service name from putty.

Hostname:acg.com
portnumber:1521
Service_name:own_db

Ping acg.com/own_db
is it right approach?
Your guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the port 1521, I suppose your database sever is running Oracle. Ths sugested way to test the connectivity with Oracle server is to use tnsping.

This is the syntax of tnsping:

`tnsping <service name>`

where the service name is the tns entry in your tnsnames.ora file. Of course, you should have Oracle client inatalled on your machine that you execute tnsping.

Answer (score 0):

Ping utility sends icmp signals (for which the only resource I found quickly was a [random forum](https://community.infosecinstitute.com/discussion/8777/icmp-port-number)), which is normally mapped to tcp or udp port 7. In order to check if a port is open (not blocked on the network by anything, including a host firewall) and that the port is listening (something is using it and accepting signals), you need to use a different tool.

`telnet` is normally used for this, although it has many more functions.

```
$ telnet 192.168.1.1 80
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> ^C
```

So you normally specify telnet (hostname) (port number). So for you, that command would be

```
telnet acg.com 1521
```

And if you get the "Connected to [IP address]" information, it connected!

You can also use `nc` which is the netcat utility. Its syntax is pretty similar, but the -v for verbose is very useful.

```
$ nc -v 192.168.1.1 80
Connection to 192.168.1.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
^C
```

Comment: "icmp ... which is normally mapped to tcp or udp port 7": AFAIK, this is false - icmp is not TCP or UDP and there is no port associated with it - can you provide a reference to where you saw that? The rest of your answer is pretty good I think.